# Variables not activating(?) Visual Studio Code (ONLY THIS ONE FOLDER)

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, visual-studio-code

In the example given, using *name in line 1 as the example for all variables, it isnt activating in any program in folder.

print, strings, for, and other commands change color; its just the variables

```
name=input('Who are you?')
print('Hello' ,name, 'Welcome to Visual Studio.')
```

other file example(Students, grades, students, name, prompt, grade, a, b ,c)...

```
import pickle
Students=[]
grades=[]
students=int(input('How many students are there? '))
for ind in range(0,students,1):
    name=(input('Student you are inquiring about, please: '))
    Students.append(name)
    prompt='Please enter '+name+"'s grade "
    grade=float(input(prompt))
    grades.append(grade)
with open('studentData.pkl','wb') as StuDat:
    pickle.dump(students,StuDat)
    pickle.dump(grades,StuDat)
    pickle.dump(Students,StuDat)
with open('studentData.pkl','rb') as StuDatRd:
    a=pickle.load(StuDatRd)
    b=pickle.load(StuDatRd)
    c=pickle.load(StuDatRd)
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "activating".

Comment: Do you mean highlighting and/or colorization by VSC to distinguish variables, classes, functions, keywords etc?

Comment: I guess the extension is not `.py`, or you've set the language to be non-Python.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your language server does not work. Have you installed `Pylance` Language Server? After installing, add `"python.languageServer": "Pylance",` in the settings.json just in case.

And you can switch or install some other theme extensions, such as `One Dark Pro`, `Dracula Official` and so on.